# Python, Selenium: send_keys("previously given input answer")

Tags: python, selenium, input

I want selenium to send_keys with the previously given answer to a input question

This is my code:

```
import urllib
import re
import sys
import time
import pyautogui
import threading
import os
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver

print("Hello and Welcome to the automated usenet account creator script")
time.sleep(0.8)
question1 = input ("Email Adress: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.5eurousenet.com/nl/cart/checkout")

time.sleep(1)

#email
email = driver.find_element_by_id('edit-panes-customer-primary-email')
email.send_keys("ANSWER TO question1")
quit()
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`question1` variable is the email value entered by user. You should just pass it as argument to `send_keys()` as:

```
email.send_keys(question1)
```